# hide() is not working in loaded modal page

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div on the modal, which should be hidden at the start of the modal opening..

This is the div that I want to hidden at first load.

```
<div id="warning" class="bg-warning warning" style="padding:2px;">
                    <h3 class="text text-danger text-center" id="warning-text">
                        Ups! Data Donatur Sudah Terdaftar
                    </h3>
                </div>
```

This is the script I'm using, but the div still shows up..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#warning').hide();
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `document.ready` fires once the document is ready, meaning fully loaded. Until it's fully loaded you will of course see the warning. You have to hide it from the start with a `hidden` class (if you use bootstrap, there should be one for you to use) or something.

Comment: What you're seeing is called a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). The problem is caused because the HTML is rendered and visible in the page *before* the JS runs and hides it. To fix this use CSS to hide the `#warning` element, as this is interpreted before the HTML loads by the renderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off hiding it with css initially by adding display: none to the style and then showing it with JavaScript when you need it.

```
<div id="warning" class="bg-warning warning" style="padding:2px; display:none;">
  <h3 class="text text-danger text-center" id="warning-text">
     Ups! Data Donatur Sudah Terdaftar
  </h3>
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript using

```
$('#warning').show();
```

For context, $(document).ready(function() {}); is called once the entire DOM has been fully loaded, so hiding it here will mean it's visible whilst the page loads and could cause flicker to the user when it is hidden in javascript.